# Cannot find '/Scripts/IntelliFactory.WebSharper.dll.js' in very basic WebSharper application

Tags: asp.net, f#, websharper

I'm developing a very simple WebSharper application and am having difficulties when running it.

My F#/WebSharper library contains Main.fs with the following:

```
namespace Sandbox35.FsLib

open IntelliFactory.WebSharper
open IntelliFactory.WebSharper.Html

type HelloWorldControl () =
    inherit Web.Control()

    [<JavaScript>]
    override this.Body =
        Div [ P [ Text "Hello World" ] ] :> Html.IPagelet
```

Which I am loading into Default.aspx, containing the following:

```html
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="Sandbox35.Lib._Default" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
  <WebSharper:ScriptManager runat="server" />
  <title>Sandbox</title>
</head>
<body>
  <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <SandboxLib:HelloWorldControl runat="server"/>
  </form>
</body>
</html>
```

I'm adding project references and where relevant and entries in the application's web.config file for my server control and handlers for WebSharper as described in the samples on their site.

It all appears to build fine but when I run the application I find that a number of Javascript files can't be found by my browser:

1. Sandbox.Lib.dll.js
2. IntelliFactory.WebSharper.dll.js
3. IntelliFactory.WebSharper.Html.dll.js

They all return with a 404 error.

I'm using VS2010 & .Net 3.5.

Just wondering what else I should check?

Answer (score 2):

The files are usually generated on disk in the Scripts folder under the root of your web project. Are they present? If not, are IntelliFactory.WebSharper.Web targets included in the web project MSBuild file?

```
<Import Project="$(WEBSHARPER_HOME)\IntelliFactory.WebSharper.Web.targets" />
```